# Unable to upload docs greater than 37 MB through CMIS API in SharePoint 2013

Tags: file-upload, sharepoint-2013, large-files, opencmis, apache-chemistry

My SharePoint 2013 version is 15.0.4569.1506. I am unable to upload a document greater than 37 MB in SharePoint through my below CMIS code. But Directly into SharePoint I am able to do so. I have also tried increasing my heap size/ cache limits. I get an Exception - 'CmisRuntimeException : Found'

```
Folder someFolder = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath("/TestFolder");

File file = new File("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/50MBFile.zip"); 
String fileName = file.getName();

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "cmis:document");
props.put("cmis:name",fileName);

String mimetype = "application/octet-stream";

ContentStream contentStream = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(fileName,
    file.length(),
    mimetype,
    new FileInputStream(file));

VersioningState versioningState = null;

Document someDoc = someFolder.createDocument(props, contentStream, versioningState );
```

I have used AtomPub Binding. Is something wrong in my code or any other SharePoint/CMIS setting I need to change ?

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisRuntimeException: Found
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:487)
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:629)
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.ObjectServiceImpl.createDocument(ObjectServiceImpl.java:119)
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionImpl.createDocument(SessionImpl.java:751)
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:95)
 at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.FolderImpl.createDocument(FolderImpl.java:469)
 at UploadLargeFile.main(UploadLargeFile.java:31)

Where this 31st line corresponds to "Document someDoc = someFolder.createDocument(props, contentStream, versioningState );"

Comment: What is the full exception with stacktrace?

Comment: Please find the attached exception

Comment: Check the IIS settings if there the is an upload restriction. A 37 MB document matches a 50 MB POST request.

Comment: In our IIS settings, the max upload size is already set to 1024 MB. We have also tried to increase connection limits through IIS Manager.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Could be a cmis limitation. please post the solution or workarround if any.
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisConnectionException: Redirects are not supported (HTTP status code 302): Found
 org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.convertStatusCode(AbstractAtomPubService.java:469)
 org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.post(AbstractAtomPubService.java:661)

Answer (score 1):

Check the maximum allowed limit in web.config files at 3 locations :

To solve this problem, you need to increase maxRequestLength value in three places on the TARGET farm:

- Central Administration web.config file (typically located in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\DirectoryName)
- Your web application main web.config file (typically located in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\DirectoryName).
- Content deployment web.config file located in:
  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\ADMIN\Content Deployment

Open web.config file located at each location and locate the maxRequestLength attribute.  Increase it to allow upload of the largest CAB file that you have.  The default setting limits the upload file size to 51200 KB for CA and web application and to 102400 KB for content deployment.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength=”102400″ />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```